# Metadata table is getting created multiple times and failing with Amazon Redshift database

Tags: amazon-redshift, flyway

I am using Gradle scripts (ver 2.3) with flyway-gradle-plugin (3.2.1) to deploy the data base changes into the Amazon Redshift Cluster database.

```
Flyway plugin: 'org.flywaydb:flyway-gradle-plugin:3.2.1'
Driver jar:'RedshiftJDBC41-1.1.2.0002.jar'  
Driver class: 'com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver'
```

Now the problem is the Metadata table is getting created twice i.e. again after (a) metadata and (b) custome sql scripts gets executed.

After executing (gradle clean build flywayMigrate --debug), only "test_schema.test_tbl" table exists, but "test_schema.DB_SCHEMA_VER" do not exists into the Redshift database.
Kindly suggest.

The complete stack trace  is as follows:

```
14:48:29.327 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl] Creating Metadata table: "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER"
14:48:29.342 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INTEGER,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
    "execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
14:48:29.342 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 30: ALTER TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" ADD CONSTRAINT "DB_SCHEMA_VER_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("version")
14:48:29.342 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INTEGER,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
    "execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
14:48:29.389 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: ALTER TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" ADD CONSTRAINT "DB_SCHEMA_VER_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("version")
14:48:29.420 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl] Metadata table "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" created.
14:48:29.420 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table] Locking table "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER"...
14:48:29.482 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.Table] Lock acquired for table "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER"
14:48:29.498 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Current version of schema "test_schema": << Empty Schema >>
14:48:29.498 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Migrating schema "test_schema" to version 1.0.0.0001 - Create tables
14:48:29.498 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 8: create table test_schema.test_tbl
(
  code varchar(30),
  description varchar(50)
)
14:48:29.498 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 14: insert into test_schema.test_tbl (code, description) values ('a1', 'test description 1')
14:48:29.498 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 15: insert into test_schema.test_tbl (code, description) values ('a2', 'test description 2')
14:48:29.514 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: create table test_schema.test_tbl
(
  code varchar(30),
  description varchar(50)
)
14:48:29.545 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: insert into test_schema.test_tbl (code, description) values ('a1', 'test description 1')
14:48:29.576 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: insert into test_schema.test_tbl (code, description) values ('a2', 'test description 2')
14:48:29.716 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.command.DbMigrate] Successfully completed and committed migration of schema "test_schema" to version 1.0.0.0001
14:48:29.732 [INFO] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.metadatatable.MetaDataTableImpl] Creating Metadata table: "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER"
14:48:29.732 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 17: CREATE TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INTEGER,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
    "execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
14:48:29.732 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Found statement at line 30: ALTER TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" ADD CONSTRAINT "DB_SCHEMA_VER_pk" PRIMARY KEY ("version")
14:48:29.732 [DEBUG] [org.flywaydb.core.internal.dbsupport.SqlScript] Executing SQL: CREATE TABLE "test_schema"."DB_SCHEMA_VER" (
    "version_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "installed_rank" INT NOT NULL,
    "version" VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    "description" VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    "type" VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    "script" VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
    "checksum" INTEGER,
    "installed_by" VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    "installed_on" TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT getdate(),
    "execution_time" INTEGER NOT NULL,
    "success" BOOLEAN NOT NULL
)
14:48:29.981 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter] Finished executing task ':flywayMigrate'
14:48:29.981 [LIFECYCLE] [class org.gradle.TaskExecutionLogger] :flywayMigrate FAILED
14:48:29.981 [INFO] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] :flywayMigrate (Thread[main,5,main]) completed. Took 1.87 secs.
14:48:29.981 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor] Task worker [Thread[main,5,main]] finished, busy: 2.774 secs, idle: 0.016 secs
14:48:29.997 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] 
14:48:29.997 [LIFECYCLE] [org.gradle.BuildResultLogger] BUILD FAILED
```

Comment: Do you see the same behavior with the regular protgresql jdbc driver?

Comment: With regular postgres jdbc driver it is unable to make the jdbc connection with the Redshift database.

Answer (score 0):

I've noticed this happens with Redshift/Flyway if the schema or table name contains characters in mixed case.

Try to configure an all-lower-case metadata table name instead, like `test_schema.db_schema_ver`, for example.